# Applying hover effect on an element without moving the cursor on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use my mouse for other purpose, for example, seeing properties or debugging using Firebug. While doing this, it's not possible to keep the cursor on an element to see the hover effect, if you are using your mouse for other tools. Is there any way so that I can apply hover effect on an element programatically?

Comment: Some browsers allow you to right click an element and force a state (chrome does this when you're debugging). - EDIT: Let me just say, you have to right click the actual html in the debug window, rather than the element on the visual page.

Comment: @BeatAlex, Firefox & firebug as well. just click F12.

Comment: Firebug has a feature that allows you to turn on hover state or see the CSS for it. See the 'style' drop down arrow by the CSS box.

Comment: @BeatAlex Thank you. This works for me. You should have answered instead of the comment.

Comment: I'll let someone else get credit for this :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here in **developer tools(F12)**, you can do it.

Check this for **Chrome** browsers.

[image: On chrome]

Here for **Firefox, using fireBug**

[image: On Firebug]

Comment: Awesome! Have never ever clicked "Toggle Element State", very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try tabbing through elements then once selected move your mouse to do w/e. or vise versa, tab through "firebugs" and use your mouse to hover.

Also if you have chrome you can inspect element and it gives a nice visual selects. Firefox does this as well. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set a focus, active, hover event on any element by using developer tools like firebug for Mozilla firefox. Open dev tool, use keyboard arrow to select the element and select **Style** dropdown from the right side to enable any of the above events. You may find the screenshot of this style option in my [image: answer].